# rails4 ckeditor (No route matches [POST] "/ckeditor/

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ckeditor

I have installed Rails4 (rails (4.1.1))
I Installed Ckeditor+paperclip (http://rubydoc.info/gems/ckeditor/4.0.11/frames)
But if I try to upload images, I get this error in log:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/ckeditor/EDITOR.config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl"):
```

i need help please! This was worked In rails 4.0.0.
My route list

> ...  mount Ckeditor::Engine => '/ckeditor'

I use Ckeditor with Paperclip

My config/routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :binaries
  resources :uploads
  resources :coms
  resources :comments

  mount Ckeditor::Engine => '/ckeditor/'

  resources :parts
  get "/parts/page/:id" => "parts#page"
  resources :answer_types
  resources :from_sender_msgs
  resources :ufknews
  get "/general" => "ufknews#general"
  get 'ufk13/ufk13pol'
  get 'ufk13/governance'
  get 'ufk13/contacts'
  get "errors/error_404"
  get "errors/error_403"
  devise_for :users
  devise_scope :user do
    get "sign_in" => "devise/sessions#new"
    get "logout" => "devise/sessions#destroy"
    delete "logout" => "devise/sessions#destroy"
    get "users" => "users#index"
    get "users/:id" => "users#show" , as: :user_root, as: :user
    get "users/:id/edit" => "users#edit" , as: :user_edit
    get "users/delete" => "users#delete"
    put "users" => "users#update"
  end
  get 'persons/profile'
  resources :budget_types
  resources :positions
  resources :message_types
  resources :message_states
  resources :messages
  resources :senders
  resources :organisations
  root 'ufknews#general'
  get 'home/index'
  get 'home/about'
  get 'home/contacts'
  get 'home/dufk'
  get 'home/photo'
  get "/*other" => redirect("/errors/error_404")
end
```

Comment: It looks like this is [a bug in ckeditor](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/issues/410).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you can modify your routes to use POST request instead PUT while try to update data with ckeditor.
For example, if you have in your routes.rb:

```
resources :pages
```

you can update this to:

```
resources :pages, :except => ['update']
post 'pages/:id' => 'pages#update'
```

It's all!

This method kill a two rabbits:

1. Modify route for ckeditor;
2. Improve your project to update big fields over header size limits on your backend of client browser.